# Vue2 get width of span and give class based on that width

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this li:

```
<li v-for="(row, index) in onceItems" :key="row.product.ID">
    <span class="title" ref="title" :class="{ max: getTitleWidth(index) > 200 }">
        {{row.product.post_title}} 
    </span>
</li>
```

I want to give the class "max" if the element is above 200px (detect long titles)

```
methods: {
    getTitleWidth: function(index) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            let width = this.$refs.title[index].clientWidth;
            console.log(width);
            return width
        })
    },
}
```

The console log returns the right value, but the class isn't given. I think it has something to do with nextTick, but without it I get an undefined value.

Comment: The return in the `nextTick` funtion is not at the level of the `getTitleHeight` function, `getTitleHeight` returns void, so it will never be more than 200, and maybe you can change the class like this: `:class="getTitleHeight(index) > 200 ? 'max' : ''"`

Comment: @Woohaik any idea how I can this working without nextTick? In simple terms: I just want to measure the width of the span, if it's more than 200px then give it a class or style property. But I think I'm missing something in the logics.

Comment: If I dont missunderstand you want to add the class when the title is long, try doing the condition based on the length of the title  :class="row.product.post_title.length  > some_number ? 'max' : ''"

Comment: @Woohaik good point, I'll try this!

Comment: @Woohaik Thank you! This was the solution :)